# Jquery AJAX with WebMethod removes zero from front

Tags: asp.net, jquery, webmethod

I have following code. Jquery Ajax calls webmethod . If i pass zipcode "07306" it returns and sets session to "7306"  . No idea why it removes zero from front!

```
function  onChangeLocation(){
        var newzip =$('#<%= txtNewLocation.ClientID %>').val();
        $('#<%= lblDefaultLocation.ClientID %>').html(newzip);
            $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "/WebMethods.aspx/ChangeLocation",
          data: "{newLocation:" + newzip + "}",
          contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
          dataType: "json",
          success: function(msg) {
          alert(msg.d);
          }
            });
       }


     [System.Web.Services.WebMethod()]
            public static String ChangeLocation(String newLocation)
            {

                HttpContext.Current.Session["ClientZipCode"] = newLocation.ToString();
                return newLocation.ToString();
            }
```

Can someone please explain why it removes zero from front ?

Comment: Why are you trying to build a JSON string and passing it to data?  Just pass it an object and force it to be a string there, e.g. `data: {newLocation: newzip + ''}`.

Comment: Use firebug or the chrome DEV tools to see what's actually getting POSTed to the server; if it's sending `07306`, then the problem is on the server side and I haven't a clue about ASP.NET, but at least you'll know where the problem is.

Comment: @El Yobo  well it was not issue on server side.  "{newLocation:'" + newzip + "'}" solved problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that JS thinks it an integer changing

```
$('#<%= lblDefaultLocation.ClientID %>').html(newzip);
```

to

```
$('#<%= lblDefaultLocation.ClientID %>').html(newzip + '');
```

Should fix it.

Comment: It won't change anything; the `newzip` value is used as is when posted to the server, not retrieved from the DOM again.  The essential problem is right though; somewhere it's being treated as an integer, so removes the leading zero.

Comment: Good Point have you tried `"{newLocation:'" + newzip + "'}"`?